# Javascript, get position of ALL repeating values in an object

Tags: javascript, compare

Have an array of notes and corresponding time, Im separating ALL the repeating Time entries with code below to a new object called duplicatesTimeValues.

```
 const allNotes =   [
        {
            "note": 69,
            "time": 0
        },
        {
            "note": 57,
            "time": 0
        },
        {
            "note": 60,
            "time": 1.5
        },
        {
            "note": 64,
            "time": 2
        },
        {
            "note": 69,
            "time": 2.5
        },
        {
            "note": 71,
            "time": 3
        },
        {
            "note": 52,
            "time": 3
        },
        {
            "note": 64,
            "time": 4.5
        },
        {
            "note": 68,
            "time": 5
        },
        {
            "note": 71,
            "time": 5.5
        }
    ];
const getDuplicates = () => {
const values = allNotes;
const lookup = values.reduce((a, e) => {
  a[e.time] = ++a[e.time] || 0;
console.log(e.keys);
  return a;
}, {});
console.log('repeating');
const duplicatesTimeValues = values.filter(e => lookup[e.time]);
console.log(duplicates);
const uniqueTimeValues = values.filter(e => !lookup[e.time]);
console.log('unique');
console.log(uniqueValues);
```

Now I need to compare this output with another array, that might look something like this

```
[57, 69, 60, 64, 69, 52, 71, 64, 68, 71]
```

but I need to be able to split that array based on how this object was split.

In order to do that, I would like to get position in original object of the repeating elements.

In this case this entries are

```
[
    {
        "note": 69,
        "time": 0
    },
    {
        "note": 57,
        "time": 0
    },
    {
        "note": 71,
        "time": 3
    },
    {
        "note": 52,
        "time": 3
    }
]
```

and result I need is

```
[0, 1, 5, 6]
```

as repeating elements were on these positions in original allNotes object. And then I will use these positions array to split array I want to compare with, so it looks like this

[60, 64, 69, 64, 68, 71]

How could I do that?

Comment: Imho is not totally clear what is the relation between the inputs `allNotes` and `[57, 69, 60, 640, 69, 52, 71, 64, 68, 71]`, and the outputs `[0, 1, 5, 6]` and the small object wihtout name (_In this case this entries are_). For instance, why is the entry with `"note"` equal to `60` not in the output?

Comment: small object is elements that are duplicates in allNotes based on their time value, output is their position in allNotes, [57, 69, 60, 64, 69, 52, 71, 64, 68, 71] is another array that I need to split in two arrays to look like this  unique [60, 64, 69,  64, 68, 71], repeating elements [57, 69, 69, 52], which I plan to accomplish by getting duplicates position in original allNotes object

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is not very clear according to me, but here is a code that gets the indexes of the duplicate elements in an array. Note that it gets the index of a duplicate only if it has been seen before (therefore you'll never get `0` in the output).

```js
const allNotes = [
  {
    note: 69,
    time: 0,
  },
  {
    note: 57,
    time: 0,
  },
  {
    note: 60,
    time: 1.5,
  },
  {
    note: 64,
    time: 2,
  },
  {
    note: 69,
    time: 2.5,
  },
  {
    note: 71,
    time: 3,
  },
  {
    note: 52,
    time: 3,
  },
  {
    note: 64,
    time: 4.5,
  },
  {
    note: 68,
    time: 5,
  },
  {
    note: 71,
    time: 5.5,
  },
];

function getIndexesOfDuplicates() {
  const indexes = [];
  const previousNotes = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < allNotes.length; i++) {
    let currentNote = allNotes[i].note;
    let found = false;
    for (let previousNote of previousNotes) {
      if (previousNote === currentNote) {
        indexes.push(i);
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!found) previousNotes.push(currentNote);
  }
  return indexes;
}

console.log(getIndexesOfDuplicates());
```

Comment: seems as a viable option, repeating times are always in sequence, so I could get 0 duplicate by subtracting 1 from first value.
Though I can't make your code work when I replace allNotes with window.allNotes, which is object I want to get duplicate indexes of.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'time')

Comment: Im also not sure why do I get this error on app starting, at that time window.allNotes is undefined, though, this function shouldn't run until I call it on button click...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner that makes use of [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15), specifically the [`lodash/fp` module](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide):

```js
let result =
  _.map(
    _.last,
    _.flatten(
      _.filter(
        x => x.length > 1,
        _.groupBy(
          _.compose(_.iteratee('time'), _.first),
          _.zip(allNotes, [...Array(allNotes.length).keys()])))))
// result now contains the array [0, 1, 5, 6]
```

- I zip `allNotes` together with their indices
- then I group them if the resulting arrays have the `'time'` of their first entry equal
- then I retain only the groups longer than 1 element, filtering out the others
- then I flatten the resulting array of groups in a single array
- and finally get the last element (which is the index appended via `_.zip`) from each entry

Comment: how do I save result in an array?
I get this when trying to log Array, Im aware that I shouldn't log array, but I don't know what else to try, im new to JS, thank

Comment: @Jan, I have no idea what you mean. Please, clarify.

Comment: Okay I see now after your edit, though I've tried that and it doesn't work, I get error -- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map'). --Should I install Lodash library?

Otherwise I just found solution as well, but it seems, your solution should be better, but can't get it working

Comment: My solution is obviously better from the readability perspective (once one accepts to make a shift of mind towards functional programming), but as regards efficiency, be aware that lodash is slow with respect to native JavaScript. And yes, you'd need to use lodash/fp module from lodash. I'll update the answer later for use with "standard" lodash.

Comment: But still I don't know how to get it working, I import Lodash by: import { _, filter, compose } from 'lodash';  -- but I get error: PianoController.js:257 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') --- should I nom install it?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to import lodash in a JavaScript project, or whatever you work on. For me, I just use it on a [blog-like thing I'm trying to set up](https://aster89.github.io/#about-me), so I basically have a line like this in my HTML: `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)"></script>`. Sorry I can't be of more help. But I'm pretty sure there's [plenty of questions and answers here on stackoverflow about how to set up lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blodash%5D+import+how).

Answer (score 0):

Found solution where I get keys of duplicate items based on values, it isn't cleanest solution, though it will work in my case, as in my use case, values are always unique...

```
const array = [];
for (var o = 0; o < duplicates.length; o++) {
const value = duplicates[o];
array.push(Object.keys(window.allNotes)[Object.values(window.allNotes).indexOf(value)]);
}
console.log(array);
```